# How do I fix this nurb path hair with head posing problem

Tags: mesh, hair, nurbs-surface

I'm trying to pose my character and made the hair all up of individual nurb paths but when I move the head with a bone attached to it with automatic weights it moves only the head and not the hair as well, and I can't just join the hair with the head because it says "no mesh data to join". I don't know much about blender so I want to know what other ways there are to fix this so it moves with the head as well.
[image]

[image]